# Missing Gemfiles in Rails Install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems, gemfile

Bit of a strange question, but here goes.

I'm a relative beginner to rails, and I've just started working on my second app locally. However, after each install I'm getting the following problem - that several gemfiles are missing (railties being the most obvious).

So, I deleted the install, re-ran it and listed the gemfiles - they are all there. However, after initializing a git repo and pushing the project up to my GitHub a `gem list` command shows that a number of gems are now missing - at this point I can't run any `rake` commands or for example `rails server`.

So I cleared the repo and re-installed. `gem list` says the gems are all present, `server` and `rake` commands work; but push the repo and it subsequently packs up - `gem list` shows only a handful of gems remain.

Bearing in mind my experience, I'm prepared to believe I'm missing something very obvious, but any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What version(s) of Rails are the two apps?

Comment: They are both 3.2.1 - but I worked out the problem. At some point between the two apps I had downloaded a version of Ruby 1.9.2 to have  a play with but not specified with rvm for the new rails app to use 1.9.3. It seems that is why dependencies were missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I forgot that I had two versions of Ruby installed and I had not properly set a default with rvm for some reason. Specifying the default then checking the gems were present for that version of Ruby fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

welcome ;-)

I suppose you want to create a Rails 3 application. So first make sure you have installed bundler.

```
gem install bundler
```

The steps for creating the application are:

```
rails new your_app
```

Then run bundler in the applications folder:

```
cd your_app
bundler install
```

Now you should be able to run the application:

```
rails s
```

Go and visit localhost:3000. If that does not work, you have other problems. Paste the stack trace then ...

Comment: My rails install says it has already installed bundler. I'm following my notes from the last app I created, and it's definitely after the git push that the rails commands stop working...

Comment: I don't understand. git push has nothing to do with your application at all. I see no reason why this should influence the proper working of your app. Honestly I do not have an idea how I could help here ... sorry